# Cocos2d-x : some sprites become invisible when a PhysicsWorld is set

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-physics, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm currently trying to make a game with cocos2d-x engine. The game, as I imagine it, needs a scrolling background. What I did then is creating 2 background sprites in a table:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    ///////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //creating "first" background 
    background[0] = Sprite::create("fond.png");
    background[0]->setPosition(0, 0);
    background[0]->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0));
    this->addChild(background[0]);

    //creating "second" background
    background[1] = Sprite::create("fond.png");
    background[1]->setPosition(background[0]->getContentSize().width, 0);
    background[1]->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0));
    this->addChild(background[1]);

    this->scheduleUpdate();
    return true;
}
```

I then made them scroll in that way, in an update function:

```
void HelloWorld::update(float delta)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) { //scrolling background
        if (background[i]->getPositionX() <= 0) {
            background[i]->setPositionX(background[i]->getPositionX()-800*delta);
            background[1-i]->setPositionX(background[1-i]->getContentSize().width+(background[i]->getPositionX()));
        }
    }
}
```

So, now, I have my basic init() and update() functions, which is great :). Now I need to do my createScene() function which, at first, looks like this:

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

And then it works perfectly! But sadly, for the rest of my game I need physics (you know, collisions and stuff), so I need to change this function to at least this:

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

And there comes the problem: when I add PhysicsWorld (like there), **background[1] becomes invisible**, like when he has to appear on the screen, I have a beautiful black screen until background[0] comes.
I have the feeling to have tried almost everything but I can't find any solution... Do somebody have an idea of what I should do?

P.S: I did all my tests on the Linux platform for the moment and I have cocos2d-x 3.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about whether or not you are using SpriteBuilder or Cocos Studio alongside your project, but in more than one GUI used alongside Cocos2d I've seen that when you set some sprite's position relative to the screen size instead of using points or UI points, it will usually spawn a lot of bugs once you move the sprite in code afterwards. 
Try setting relative positions in code from the moment they are loaded or do not use relative initial positioning for moving sprites in the GUI you are using.